# The preview in Android Studio is not the same as the app running on the emulator

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-studio

I’m new to Android programming and I’m already facing a problem with the simplest thing one could imagine: placing a button on the screen. In the preview of the activity.xml file everything is fine but in the emulator it’s messed up, the buttons and labels are not where they should be.

Here is an example: I put a button to the left of the floating action button but in the emulator it’s way above it.

Android Studio Preview:

[image: Android Studio Preview]

Emulator:

[image: Emulator]

Here is the XML code:

```
activity.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.ed.wtf.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



content.xml

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.example.ed.wtf.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Put floatingActionButton in content main and add alignParentBottom to it

Comment: And also, make sure in preview layout, set the theme the same as it is in manifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

why this difference is coming i dont know but when you give width and height to layout then it will show same in emulator and studio preview.

```
 <include layout="@layout/content_main" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

chose the same resolution, inches and pixel for your preview and emulator
from device editor in window of preview

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to elaborate on your answer for future readers. Perhaps add the steps a user should take to set the resolution? Including screenshots would help even more!